# How do I add this query to the column in my table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I want to add this query to  a column in my table.I am using pgadmin

```
select  customer_id,
         count(*)
from  summary
group by customer_id
order by customer_id asc
```

I got as far as

```
ALTER TABLE summary
add  sum_of_rentals INT

UPDATE SUMMARY
SET sum_of_rentals =
(
select count(*)
    FROM summary
    WHERE customer_id= customer_id
    GROUP BY customer_id
)
```

I tried this

```
 UPDATE SUMMARY
SET sum_of_rentals =
(
select count(*)
    FROM summary
    WHERE customer_id= customer_id
    GROUP BY customer_id
)
```

and got this answer from pgadmin

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

> SQL state: 21000

Comment: how does the table sumary looks like, you can't do your query because you need a scalar return value and not a rwiset

Comment: Are you sure you want to SELECT and UPDATE from the same table? If so, it would be an unusual data model. Please check

Comment: Why would you want to add it as a column? It will just get out of date quickly. Instead create a view that shows the results of the query.

Answer (score 0):

in don't know, what for you need that query.

But as i said in the comment, you produce with your subquery a rowset with as many rows a you have customers, but postgres exoects a sclar value

so one solution is to make a correlated subquery

```
CREATE tABLE summary (customer_id int);
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
INSERT INTO summary VALUEs (1),(1),(2),(3)
```

> ```
> INSERT 0 4
> ```

```
ALTER TABLE summary
add  sum_of_rentals INT;
```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE
> ```

```
UPDATE summary s1
SET sum_of_rentals =
(
select count(*)
    FROM summary
    WHERE customer_id= s1.customer_id

)
```

> ```
> UPDATE 4
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM summary
```

| customer_id | sum_of_rentals |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |

> ```
> SELECT 4
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IXJtQxLX)

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you want to calculate the total rentals for each customer and apply that total to every row associated with that particular customer in the table.

```
UPDATE SUMMARY s
SET sum_of_rentals = t.sum_of_rentals
FROM SUMMARY su
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) AS sum_of_rentals 
  FROM SUMMARY
  GROUP BY customer_id
) AS t ON su.customer_id = t.customer_id
WHERE s.customer_id = su.customer_id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/51O3Gqgo)

Answer (score 0):

```
update summary
set sum_of_rentals = (
    select count(*)
    from summary
    where customer_id= customer_id
    group by customer_id
)
```

In the subquery, `customer_id= customer_id` is referring to `customer_id` for the rows being selected. You're querying rows whose customer_id equals their customer_id which is all rows so you get multiple results. You need to disambiguate them by using table aliases and fully qualified column names.

```
update summary
set sum_of_rentals = (
    select count(*)
    from summary sub
    where summary.customer_id = sub.customer_id
    group by sub.customer_id
)
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/52sb2IAF)

---

Note: you may wish to move statistical caching like this into a join table. Then if you have 1,000,000 rows but only 1,000 unique values you only have 1,000 rows to update.

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/fJh09RWw).

Regardless, you probably want to keep it up to date with an insert/update/delete trigger.